# Minimize variable function tensorflow with placeholder

Tags: python, tensorflow, minimization

I would like to do a minimization that finds the best fitting phase shift to a sin function. 
In this example I provide

> sin(x + 2.01)

and through the minimization I would like to find that the best fitting sine function that matches the above returns *phase = 2.01*.

The objective of the loss function is summation (of each time instance) of squared differences.

I included the code below,

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.training import gradient_descent

phase = tf.Variable(0, trainable=True, dtype='float64', name='phase_tf')
y = tf.placeholder(dtype='float64', name="y_placeholder")
t = tf.placeholder(dtype='float64', name='t_placeholder')

test_t = np.linspace(0, 6, 100, dtype='float64')
test_y = np.sin(test_t + 2.01)
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y - tf.math.sin(t + phase)))

opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run([phase, loss]))
    sess.run(opt, feed_dict={y:test_y, t:test_t})
```

However, I am not able to work around this error

```
InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 't_placeholder_15' with dtype double
     [[{{node t_placeholder_15}} = Placeholder[dtype=DT_DOUBLE, shape=<unknown>, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

My guess is that the values are not fed to the placeholder correctly, however I do feed them into the session. I know this can also be done in scipy more easily, but would like to do it in tensorflow :)

Comment: You are not feeding anything for `y` when you are running `[phase, loss]` in the session. Thus `loss` cannot be computed (it needs a value for `y`).

Comment: Having a fresh look at this, the problem indeed was to add feed_dict to the session run. Thanks for helping!